# GFCI outlet trips overnight. The breaker indicates there is ground fault. Outlet tester shows no lights (no power?)

Tags: gfci, garbage-disposal

I have a GFCI tripping problem. My garbage disposal is connected to an outlet protected by a GFCI breaker. I am still able to run the disposal several times within one or two hours after I reset the breaker of garbage disposal. HOWEVER, the next morning, it is always tripped... The breaker indicates ground fault. Outlet tester shows no lights (indicating no power?). I am not familiar with electricity at all. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there anything else _at all_ on that circuit? If you turn off the breaker that disables the disposal, does anything else turn off.

Comment: I don't think so. When it's tripped, we don't find anything else not working properly. Also in the breaker panel, it says it's for disposal which I interpret as "for disposal ony".

Comment: GFCI breakers and receptacles are sensitive electronic devices and Motor loads like your disposal are electrically noisy and may have damaged the GFCI. I might change out the breaker to see if it is faulty. 2 year old disposal is not very old at all  but your breaker not properly resetting is an issue and the reason I would replace it .

Answer (score 3):

The outlet tester shows no lights, because there is no power until you reset the GFCI.

A GFCI can trip because there is a ground fault or because the GFCI itself is bad. Most of the time, it is an actual ground fault - a life-safety condition. Consider the different possibilities:

- The disposal has a fault which only appears after an extended period of time. For example, there could be a very small leak of water into the motor. It could be that it is a very slow leak, so it does not show up on immediate use, but does trip the GFCI after several hours of drip-drip-drip. Then it trips in the middle of the night. By the time you get to it, the water has dried out and you are able to reset the GFCI and use the disposal again for a while. **Key question: How old is the disposal?** Any signs of cracks in the case? Any water under the sink, anywhere?
- A downstream device has a fault. A GFCI can be connected to multiple devices (receptacles or hard-wired) using the **LOAD** connections. This is unlikely for a disposal receptacle, but it is possible. If that is the case, or if you have something else plugged in to the 2nd receptacle (assuming it is a typical dual receptacle) then a different device could be causing the problem.
- Water dripping into the receptacle. A long-shot, but if there is water leaking under the sink and *slowly* making its way down the cord to the receptacle, that could cause a GFCI trip. If that's the case, you want to to trace back to the disposal, drain and sink to find where water is leaking.

Based on discussion in comments, it is not clear whether the disposal is causing the trip or something else. Suggestion: Next time you use the disposal for the "usual" amount, assuming you have no GFCI trip at the time, unplug it. Then the next morning see if you find:

- GFCI tripped before you plug in the disposal. This would indicate a problem with something else on the circuit or with the GFCI breaker itself.
- GFCI trips immediately upon plugging in the disposal or after plugging in as soon as you try turning the disposal on. This would indicate a problem in the disposal itself.
- Disposal runs fine for a while after plugging it in. This would indicate some sort of leakage inside the disposal causing the "usual" trip and drying out before you plug it in (or on a regular day, drying out before you reset the GFCI).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I did reset the GFCI in the breaker before I tested the outlet. In fact, immediately after I got no lights from the outlet tester, I connected the disposal and it ran ok. My disposal is about 2 years old (it's a new condo I bought two years go and it came with it). Didn't notice there is any water leak.

Comment: If your first point is the cause, what would you suggest in this situation?  Thanks!

Comment: No lights from the tester, yet the disposal ran OK? That seems odd. Is the GFCI in the receptacle (TEST/RESET buttons right next to the outlets) or is the GFCI in the "breaker panel"?

Comment: If the problem is actually in the disposal, then it is time for a new disposal. That would be unusual for a 2-year-old disposal - they typically last 10 - 15 years - but not impossible.

Comment: I thought it was odd too....The test/reset button is in the breaker panel. The tester works fine with other GFCI outlet...

Comment: That is a clue. I changed the Question to clarify that the GFCI is in the breaker rather than the receptacle. That rules out cumulative damage due to water leaks (water would still trip the GFCI but not get into the electronics of it). **Does anything else stop working when the GFCI trips?** Lights? Counter receptacles?

Comment: All lights and counter receptacles are fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your method and update later.

Comment: It turns out that GFCI tripped before I plug in the disposal. So according to your comments, either something else on the circuit or the GFCI breaker itself causes the problem. Do you have any suggestion on how to find out which is true? It's probably the latter because no other lights or outlets are affected when it's tripped. What can be done to fix the GFCI breaker? Thank you again!

Comment: Sounds like it's the breaker. If so, the solution is to replace the breaker. Must be same or listed compatible with the specific panel and same size (15 or 20 amp same as now)

Comment: Thanks. I believe it's the breaker. I reset the breaker and did not plug back in the disposal. The GFCI was still tripped in about two hours.

Comment: @loop -- check other boxes on that circuit...(there's also the off chance it's a fault in the wiring itself)